# Words used to describe the process of redefining words abusively

Tags: word-request, idiom-request, concessives

What word can be used to describe the process of redefining words abusively, and the words so abusively defined or redefined.

For instance, suppose something quite natural normally occurring as a human condition was defined or redefined as a disease, in order to sell pharmaceutical "cures" that actually did havoc, and this was a marketing strategy of the pharmaceutical companies. People would rush to get the medication, finding themselves amidst problems they never imagined.

What English word can be used to describe this abusive redefining of words?

Thanks.

Comment: This isn't an idiom, just a relevant idea from sociology: **DISASTER CAPITALISM** https://www.dictionary.com/browse/disaster-capitalism

Answer (score 1):

The closest term for abusive redefining of words that comes to my mind is **intentional misinterpretation.**

> Manipulation Games 9: **Intentional Misinterpretation.** In this
>   manipulation game the manipulator purposefully mis-interprets the
>   meaning of words, sentences, whole scenes or the motivation and
>   intention...([soundsoulcounselling.com](http://soundsoulcounseling.com/manipulation-games-9-intentional-misinterpretatio/))

**Deception** = the act of causing someone to accept as true or valid what is false or invalid : the act of deceiving ([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/deception)).

**Fabricating** = to devise or invent, to fake ([Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/fabricate?s=t))

**Disinformation** is false information spread deliberately to deceive ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disinformation)).